# Is there any code in angular for tabs which doesn't load data in browse initially but loads it only when we click it

Tags: php, angularjs, json, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

[this is what it shows on clicking tab one time 2nd time I click it loads last two file .15 and .17 again alltogether](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9T4m.png)this is shown in console when I inspect even if I have not clicked on tab.And displays this data in browser when I click tab. This should not be shown whn console is clicked while inspectin page. Data only to be loaded only when I click tab.

Object {type: "FeatureCollection", metadata: Object, features:Array[11], bbox: Array[6]}bbox: Array[6]features: Array[11]metadata: Objecttype: "FeatureCollection"**proto**: Object

```
 here is my code..
 <body  ng-controller="CountryCtrl">
   <div  ng-app ng-init="tab=1">
   <div class="cb" ng-click="tab = 1">tab 1</div>
   <div class="cb" ng-click="tab = 2">tab 2</div>



    <div ng-show="tab == 1">
     <p>hellloollllllllllllo</p>
    </div>


   <div ng-show="tab == 2">

        <h2>Angular.js JSON Fetching Example</h2>




            <table border=1>
            <tr>
            <th>type</th>
            <th>properties_mag</th>
            <th>properties_place</th>
            <th>properties_time</th>
            <th>properties_upated</th>
            <th>properties_tz</th>

            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="type in country ">

            <td>{{type.type}}</td>
            <td>{{type.properties.mag}} </td>
            <td> {{type.properties.place}} </td>
            <td> {{type.properties.time}} </td>
            <td> {{type.properties.updated}} </td>
            <td> {{type.properties.tz}} </td>

            <tr ng-repeat="cor in features.geometry.coordinates ">
            <td> {{cor}} </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

```
this is controller function.....

  var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp',[]);
  countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('http:/4.5_day.geojson').success(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $scope.country = data.features;
      $scope.coor=data.features.geometry.coordinates;
      console.log($scope.country);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Could you show us some of the code you currently have ?

Comment: below I have posted my code that i am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you simply call the function that loads the JSON data when clicking the second tab using ng-click. This way you will not get it loaded unless the tab is clicked.

You could change:

```
<div class="cb" ng-click="tab = 2">tab 2</div>
```

To:

```
<div class="cb" ng-click="switchTabAndLoadData()">tab 2</div>
```

And defined the function in your controller to update the tab variable and load the JSON.

You are calling the $http service directly in your controller that's why the data is loaded up front. Try this:

```
         var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp',[]);
          countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function ($scope, $http){

         var loadData = function(){  
$http.get('http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_day.geojson').success(function(data) {
              console.log(data);
              $scope.country = data.features;
              $scope.coor=data.features.geometry.coordinates;
              console.log($scope.country);
            });
         }
         $scope.switchTabAndLoadData = function(){
           $scope.tab=2;
           if(angular.isUndefined($scope.country) || angular.isUndefined($scope.coor)){ 
               loadData();
           }
         }
          });
```

Make sure to also apply the HTML change I previously suggested and it should be fine.

You problem lies elsewhere, had you checked the console you would have seen that angular gives an error on your assignment of variables for `$scope.coor` since you are trying to assign properies of an object in an array of object.

Check this pen for a solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjXGGJ

You can then adjust the HTML do your needs.

Comment: still console shows the json data , that means browser is loading data :(

Comment: Make sure to only call your function that loads data inside the switchTabAndLoadData(). Could you show the controller code? That would help understand the issue.

Comment: You need to update your controller code to achieve what you want, please try the code I posted. I have updated my answer above.

Comment: Its working but every time I click on tab it is fetching data, means once I clicked tab data should be cached it should not show loaded data every time in console. it should load that once only when I click tab not every time I click tab

Comment: Then just check whether the data is loaded when clicking the tab. See the if statement in the updated code above.

Comment: no difference loads data after clicking on tab but every time I click tab it fetches data means if i click tab once it should load data. second time if i click it then it fetch that cached data.

Comment: make sure the checks in the if are properly working, I didn't test the code myself but the main idea is the you should only call the function when the data is not loaded so just try to check in console the result of `angular.isUndefined($scope.country)` or the other check and perhaps find a better check if it is necessary.

Comment: thanks for your help. I have posted an image above which is shown in blue link

Comment: can you please revert it back to old code that was much better .

Comment: I made some changes and its working fine problem solved thank a lot RAUL :)

Comment: Provided a link to codepen with a fix. You're welcome.

Comment: I removed second condition from if, now its working fine thanks a lot :D